# Shrinkwrapping around an object gets cut off

Tags: shrinkwrap

I modeled this screen that I want to shrinkwrap around a column, but when I use the mod, it doesn't go all the way around, is there a better way to make this go all the way around?

[image: Screen as a plane image]

[image: After shrinkwrap mod]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possibility is to give the plane enough subdivisions and then use the simple deform - bend modifier.

So you will get something like this:

[image]